# Finding a reference to a cell in an excel formula

Tags: excel, vba, reference, formula

Is there a formula or a macro that can find a reference to a cell in another cell?
For example:

```
   A  |  B  |   C
------------------
1| 1  |  2  | =A1+B1
```

is there a formula that takes a `C1` as input and returns `=1+2`?

Comment: try the function indirect()

Comment: Take a look at the "Evaluate Formlua" tool in the formula tab.

Comment: =C1? The question is not clear as stated - C1 does not include "a reference", but a formula. If C1 held "D1" for example, then the `INDIRECT()` formula applies. I suspect that you want to parse the formula in C1 to firstly identify the ranges, and the non-range text so that you can redisplay. In that case, consider using a `Replace` formula (along with whatever else is needed) to replace the range information (e.g. `A1`) with `INDIRECT(<found range identifier>)`. But, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this User Defined Function to convert the cell references used in the formula to their values as per your requirement.

Place the following Function on a Standard Module like Module1.

```
Function CellRefereceToValue(ByVal rng As Range) As String
Dim re As Object, Matches As Object, Match As Object
Dim str As String
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With re
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "[A-Z]+\d+"
End With

str = rng.Formula

If re.test(str) Then
    Set Matches = re.Execute(str)
    For Each Match In Matches
        str = Replace(str, Match, Range(Match).Value)
    Next Match
End If
CellRefereceToValue = str
End Function
```

And then assuming your formula is in C2 as per the following image, use this Function on the Sheet like below...

```
=CellRefereceToValue(C2)
```

In the following image, Excel formulas are placed in column C and formula text in column D to show what formula is used in column C and then in column E, you can see the UDF replacing all the cell references used in the formulas in column C with their corresponding values.

[image]